# Grid with custom JsonRest not loading data

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, dojo.gridx, jsonreststore

I have grid(gridx/Grid) connected with my custom store which extends dojo/store/JsonRest.

My server call gets success and store.data will loaded properly.

I have my custom query() method in my store(extends JsonRest). Instead of GET request I use POST request in query() method.

```
query: function(){
//....custom config.......
 var xhrArgs = {
              url: this.url,
              postData: postData,
              handleAs: "json",
              headers: {'Accept':'application/json','Content-Type':'application/json'},
              load: function(data)
              {
            // ....data customization....
                store.data = customizedData;

              },
              error: function(error)
              {
            console.log(error);
              }
        }
var results =  dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);

results.then(function(response){

// ....data customization....
    store.data = customizedData;
return customizedData;
});
return QueryResults(results);

}
```

I have returned dojo/store/util/QueryResults in query() method and my custom function (in then method).All are working fine. Only thing is grid not populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Found it!!!

Deffered is the culprit!!

We should return customized data to the QueryResults not xhr object.

So my query method should be like this

```
query: function(){
    //....custom config.......
     var xhrArgs = {
          url: this.url,
          postData: postData,
          handleAs: "json",
          headers: {'Accept':'application/json','Content-Type':'application/json'},
          load: function(data)
          {
        // ....data customization....
            store.data = customizedData;

          },
          error: function(error)
          {
        console.log(error);
          }
            }
    var results =  dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);


//********************************** THIS IS RIGHT WAY ***************
    var resolvedObject = results.then(function(response){

    // ....data customization....
        store.data = customizedData;
    return customizedData;
    });
    return QueryResults(resolvedObject);
}
```

When we pass resolved object to QueryResults it appends all IterativeMethods like **forEach** with **resolvedObject** and returned that object to grid.

Then only grid iterate the result object.Actually grid does

```
store.query().forEach(##ADD ITEMS TO GRID##))
```